# How to run code after fetching data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

I have a JSON file containing an array full of products and want to create a global array containing the JSON data.

When I tried the following code the array variable was printed before the data variable.

```
var array;

fetch("products.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data); // The data variable contains the data
            
    array = data;
})

console.log(array); // The array variable is undefined
```

So I tried to print the array variable after 500ms which is enough to fetch the data and the array variable was containing the data.

```
var array;

fetch("products.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data); // The data variable contains the data
            
    array = data;
})
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(array); // The array variable contains the data
}, 500);
```

How can I print the array directly after the fetching is finished?

Comment: There's one, like, every day. Either use async/await (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to make it neater, or put it inside the `then`, there really is no other way to _instruct javascript to wait until the data is there_.

Comment: Hard to understand asynchrony is

Comment: And every time I try to find one of the already existing answers to vote to close, I can't find any!